# Update one table by aggregating data of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables:

**likes: userid, postid**

**user_images: postid, username, images, likes**

All of the likes are stored in the Table **"likes"**, but all the likes in the **"user_images"** are at 4 for all users. Is there a way to run a query that UPDATES all the likes from **"user_images"** table to correspond the amount that is in the **"likes"** table.

For example, postid (5) has 10 likes (10 userids) in **"likes"** therefore the postid of **"user_images"** (5) should have the value of 10 likes instead of 4.

I hope this wasn't too confusing.

Comment: Why do you need to store a total in `user_images`?

Comment: If you don't find an easy way of running a single query, it should not be too hard to write some kind of script to help you out

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton probably because you store *who* liked each image - not just the number of likes.

Comment: @Charleh Yeah, but you can get the count of likes for any given post by just selecting all of the rows with a specific ID.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton true, you can just derive it - and to be honest based on the question it's unlikely that this decision was an intentional optimisation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (using transactions):

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE user_images 
   SET likes=(SELECT count(*) 
                FROM likes 
               WHERE likes.postid=user_images.postid);
```

Do a check if updated correctly looking at result in user_images table:

```
SELECT * FROM user_images;
```

If everything is ok, commmit the transaction:

```
COMMIT;
```

BUT, if something wrong, do rollback:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

And comment to try a new approach.

Comment: Ok, thank you, would I insert this in phpmyadmin?

Comment: First run the `BEGIN` to create a transaction, if something went wrong you can return, execute the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` and check if your result is OK. If OK, you run `COMMIT` command, else, `ROLLBACK`. And yes, you can run those commands in your phpMyAdmin.

Comment: All of the likes are restored! Thank you so much! One more question though, with rollback, can you do it by time? Like set it back a day ago?

Comment: Rollback runs only in the active `BEGIN`. If you execute first `BEGIN;` you can do `ROLLBACK` to revert and `COMMIT` to apply the changes but only on the running transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Why store a total at all? You could just get a fresh count of likes on any given post in a single query, and just get rid of that total column completely.

Counts for all posts:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.postid=user_images.postid) as likes FROM user_images;
```

Results:

```
| postid | username | images | likes |
|--------|----------|--------|-------|
|      1 |    test1 |   test |     3 |
|      2 |    test2 |   test |     5 |
|      3 |    test3 |   test |     0 |
```

Or, if you need a count only for a specific post, just use a `WHERE` clause at the end of your query.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.postid=user_images.postid) as likes FROM user_images WHERE postid=2;
```

Results:

```
| postid | username | images | likes |
|--------|----------|--------|-------|
|      2 |    test2 |   test |     5 |
```

This method will make it so you don't have to update the total every time you insert a new like, and you also wouldn't be able to accidentally set all of the totals to something incorrect without removing all of the likes from the database.

Comment: Thank you! Everything I made was a few years ago and didn't think about it efficiently